Create a gitlab ci pipeline for build a WPF .net8 project and run unit tests
I'm having difficulty configuring my GitLab CI pipeline to properly build and test a .NET 8 WPF project. I'm unsure how to configure the pipeline YAML file to ensure that both build and test stages are triggered for each push. Also, I'm encountering compatibility issues with running my .NET 8 WPF project and xUnit tests on Linux runners.
I've tried a first version like this:
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0

stages:
  - build
  - test

workflow:
  rules:
    - when: always

before_script:
  - cd MyProject.MyProject

build-job:
  stage: build
  script:
    - dotnet restore
    - dotnet build

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - 'dotnet test --logger "html;LogFileName=test-results.html;MethodFormat=Class;FailureBodyFormat=Verbose"'
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR\**\test-results.html
    expire_in: 1 week

The build stage works perfectly, otherwise for the test stage I had this error:
Architecture: x64
Framework: 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App', version '8.0.0' (x64)
.NET location: /usr/share/dotnet/
No frameworks were found.
Learn more:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed
To install missing framework, download:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App&framework_version=8.0.0&arch=x64&rid=linux-x64&os=debian.12
. Please check the diagnostic logs for more information.

Test Run Aborted.

After multiple tries I decided to use windows runner instead:
.windows_runners:
  tags: [shared-windows, windows, windows-1809]
  before_script:
    - cd MyProject.MyProject

stages:
  - build
  - test

workflow:
  rules:
    - when: always
  
build-job:
  stage: build
  extends:
    - .windows_runners
  script:
    - dotnet restore
    - dotnet build

test:
  stage: test
  extends:
    - .windows_runners
  script:
    - 'dotnet test --logger "html;LogFileName=test-results.html;MethodFormat=Class;FailureBodyFormat=Verbose"'
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR\**\test-results.html
    expire_in: 1 week

With that everything is working great but it will take at least 20 minutes to run those two stages (build and test) which is not efficient for our workflow.
Do you have some recommendations to achieve this goal?
Thanks for your help :)

WPF and the Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App SDK is Windows only.
